# 'il s'ennuie' or 'il est ennuie'. Which is correct?

Tags: traduction, anglais, formulation-idiomatique, conjugaison, verbes-pronominaux

I am bit confused on this:

*Il s'ennuie.* (ou) *Il est ennuie.* which is right?

When I google, it looks like the first one is correct. Not sure why second one is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is correct indeed:

> *Il s'ennuie.* - He is bored.

The second might be modified to:

> *Il est ennuyé.*

but the meaning is slightly different (He is bothered / annoyed.)

Answer (score 0):

The first turn is the correct one. The verb s'ennuyer is a prenominal one. See, for instance, https://www.larousse.fr/conjugaison/francais/s%27ennuyer/4106

> Il s'ennuie (present tense, 3rd person of singular).

Cf.

> Il s'est ennuyé (present perfect, aka passé composé, 3rd person of singular).

Prenominal verbs are conjugated with the auxiliary verb être in compound tenses.

Note also that there is the turn:

> Il est ennuyé

'être ennuyé' is a passive verb.

According to https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ennuyer/29683 it conveys

> Éprouver de la contrariété, du souci pour telle ou telle raison ; être
> préoccupé : Je suis ennuyé de vous savoir malade.

Comment: Understood. Merci.